# Different class in HTML depending of screen size

Tags: javascript, django, html, bootstrap-4

I'm newbie in bootstrap and I don't know how to do the following:
I'm working with Django and in my HTML template I have this:

```
<div class="tabs tabs-vertical tabs-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

This works fine with large screens, but it looks ugly when I access into the page with my phone, so I need that my template look like this if the screen is xs:

```
<div class="tabs">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified flex-column flex-md-row">
```

Can this be done with bootstrap? It's necessary to clone the entire div content and hide depending of screen? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please post all of the relevent code. It's not clear what the question is. Are you trying to make left tabs move of the top on xs screens. There is no `tabs-left` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use javascript to add the classes if the screen width is less that your desired breakpoint. Since you're using Bootstrap, you can use jQuery to make it easier. Example:

```js
if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
  $('#nav').removeClass('tabs-vertical tabs-left');
  $('#navUl').addClass('nav-justified flex-column flex-md-row');
}

console.log(document.getElementById('nav').classList);
console.log(document.getElementById('navUl').classList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs tabs-vertical tabs-left" id='nav'>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id='navUl'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can use that if statement to do what you want. If you attach it to `$(window).resize();` event you can update it to add the styles and remove them responsively.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mobiledetect.js script, and depending on what device it registers, send it to a different CSS script that would fit it for each type of device (i.e. mobile, pc, etc.)

Script download:
http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/